# Proper use of @user replies?

Tags: support, comments

I intend to use an @user reply in a comment, responding to Deer Hunter about a question he answered. I am not sure how to deal with the space in his name. Should I use @DeerHunter or @Deer Hunter or something else?

Answer (score 5):

Automatic text completion should help alleviate the confusion. As you start to type the @username into the comment:

<kbd>@</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>e</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>

…the text completion should show you how it is entered: `@DeerHunter`. Hit <kbd>tab</kbd> to complete the text.

See [Replying in comments](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)

Comment: Thanks @Robert. It seems that text completion is not functioning on my browser...

Comment: I can add that the poster of a question or answer receives notification if comments are added to his post, so the @mention is not necessary unless replying to another commenter.